# how to make users to add my custom tabs to their pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

im having the manage_pages permission for the users....But how to make the users to make add my custom tab with this link in php..

```
 http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=APP_ID&method=POST &access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I have fetched all the pages of my users, when they select any page from their list of pages, that custom tab should be added to their facebook page directly...

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'tabs' connection of a page in the Graph API.

Docs are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Once you have the page access token (for '{PAGE_ID}' below) it should be as simple as a request to `/{PAGE_ID}/tabs/{APP_ID}?access_token={PAGE ACCESS TOKEN}`

Comment: I even referred the above docs but they are not very clear to me to understand...did get them how to use...in php?

Comment: Have you tried? What problem did you encounter? Once you have the page access token it should be as simple a request to `/{PAGE_ID}/tabs/{APP_ID}?access_token={PAGE ACCESS TOKEN}`

Comment: Am the beginner to these codings...How can i try...
      `<script>
window.getPages = function() {
    FB.api('/me/accounts', function(resp) {
        var ul = document.getElementById('pages');
        for (var i=0, l=resp.data.length; i<l; i++) {
            var
            page= resp.data[i];
            li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = " <a href='http://facebook.com/"+page.id+"'>"+page.name+"</a>"; ;
            ul.appendChild(li);
        } 
   });
}; 
</script>`
How can i try that in this code..suggest me Igy

Comment: can you suggest me how to use this code in my above codings
/{PAGE_ID}/tabs/{APP_ID}?access_token={PAGE ACCESS TOKEN}..